# Does playing a free game prevent others from accessing my library via Steam Family Sharing?

Tags: steam, steam-family-sharing

My brother and I recently enabled [Steam Family Sharing](https://store.steampowered.com/promotion/familysharing), so that we can play each other's games.

However, I regularly play [a game that's entirely free](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1118310/RetroArch/); no paid DLC, no microtransactions, no subscriptions, nothing. **If I'm playing a free game, will that prevent my brother from accessing my library during that session?**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

We just tried this out; I started RetroArch, and then my brother started one of the games from my library. **There was no problem, he can play the game successfully.**

Comment: :) Of course, don't forget to self-accept tomorrow.